# Disable input in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, disabled-input

I'm creating the 8 puzzle box game in Javascript and Jquery mobile. I've done the boxes with an `<input readonly></input>` and I've putted all of them in a 9x9 table. The problem is that when I click on a box to move it,even if it is readonly, the mobile device try to write in it and shows the keyboard. This is not what I want...I want to disable the input or use something different from `<input>`. I tried with disable="disabled" but still doesn't work.
This is the code:

```
<form name="box">
    </center>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td ><input name="casella1" value="8" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella2" value="5" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella3" value="2" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><input name="casella4" value="6" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella5" value="3" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella6" value="4" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ><input name="casella7" value="1" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella8" value="7" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>
            <td ><input name="casella9" value="" onClick="test(this.value)" readonly style="text-align: center; width:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #C0C0C0; border-style: solid; border-color: black"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use `disabled="disabled"` instead of `disable="disable"` !

Comment: No, it was a spelling error that I made here, but I wrote disabled="disabled" in the code! It doesn't work because the javascript code isn't executed (onClick is disabled) and the mobile device still shows the kyboard! There isn't another way?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").attr("disabled","true");
```

is the jQuery solution, and setting `disabled` in markup is the html solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using HTML5, then including `disabled` attribute would suffice, as it's a Boolean attribute.